# Delete data from All collection of mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have 3 db with hundreds of collection in each db. I need to delete data with `MDATE:'2020125'` from all collection in all DBs
`db.A.remove({MDATE:'2020125'})` work fine for `A` collection and I have to run this on `AA` collection as well as `AAA` and so on...
is there any way to do this in on batch?

**Edition:**

after 2 month no answer posted here. the way i followed creating Script for any db and collections. it seems that there is limitation here

Comment: basically no, such way does not exist.

Comment: Dear tom slabbaert, then they only way is to get collections name and create script for all? 'db.getCollectionNames()'

Comment: @Mohsen Yes, build a script for each collection name, run `remove` method